# How automatically update an html content (from database) without recharge the page (F5, <meta...>, etc.) and without a click event?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I need update my web content without using a click event or a page recharge (F5,  hmtl tag). I wnat do this automatically, with a frequency of 2 minutes. Thanks!

Comment: You'll want to use AJAX.

Comment: i try but ajax is only with a button event, correct?

Comment: No, you can use a timer.

Answer (score 0):

To load content from your server you need AJAX:

```
function getServerData(){
    $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "some.php",
            data: 
            { 
                param1:"something"
            }
        })
        .done(function(response)
        {
            // Update HTML 
            console.log(response);
        })
        .fail(function(d)
        {
            console.log(d);
        });
}
```

To do it every 2 mins:

```
setInterval(getServerData, 1200000);
```